# How to combine two different sets of identifiers in Google Dataflow?

Tags: java, etl, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've got two, quite big sets of data, each one is ~600GB.

The first one signature is:

- `KV<String,String>` where both `String` represent identifiers from **Database A**. It actually represent a relation between them.
- `KV<String,Long>` where `String` is an identifier from **Database A** and `Long` is an identifier from **Database B**. This relation represent how `String` from **Database A** is mapped to `Long` in **Database B**.

I would like to receive an outcome with signature: `KV<Long,Long>` which is exactly the same size as `KV<String,String>` but the values are taken from `KV<String,Long>` which is effectively treated as a huge `HashMap`.

I can image that this is a quite common problem in many ETLs. Can someone give me a hint where to start?

Answer (score 1):

How many relationships does a given identifier have?

If the answer is not that many, you could use `CoGroupByKey`
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/join/CoGroupByKey.html

`CoGroupByKey` transforms this:

```
final List<KV<String, String>> emailsList =
    Arrays.asList(
        KV.of("amy", "amy@example.com"),
        KV.of("carl", "carl@example.com"),
        KV.of("julia", "julia@example.com"),
        KV.of("carl", "carl@email.com"));

final List<KV<String, String>> phonesList =
    Arrays.asList(
        KV.of("amy", "111-222-3333"),
        KV.of("james", "222-333-4444"),
        KV.of("amy", "333-444-5555"),
        KV.of("carl", "444-555-6666"));
```

into this:

```
final List<String> formattedResults =
    Arrays.asList(
        "amy; ['amy@example.com']; ['111-222-3333', '333-444-5555']",
        "carl; ['carl@email.com', 'carl@example.com']; ['444-555-6666']",
        "james; []; ['222-333-4444']",
        "julia; ['julia@example.com']; []");
```

You could do `CoGroupByKey` twice, once for each string from `KV<String,String>`. Both times, pair it with `KV<String,Long>`.

However, if a given identifier has a large amount of relationships, the default `CoGroupByKey` may not be very efficient and may even run out of memory (since the number of matches for the `KV<String,String>` array could be huge).

It sounds like you may need to concoct your own version of `CoGroupByKey` / `GroupByKey` to yield values as you go instead of building them up in an array.

If you look at the source code, you'll see that `CoGroupByKey` & `GroupByKey` are just `PTransform`s.

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/join/CoGroupByKey.java

Comment: On average, each identifier has 2 relationships, but the actual range if even up to 100k and they will definitely fit into memory at once - but these are only few of them. I will try to dig into this CoGroupByKey.

Comment: I also saw that Side-inputs are used in such cases, but I don't know if there is a way to pass it since it doesn't really fit into memory. Any ideas if that would work?

Comment: I'm not sure. Looking at this https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs, it seems that in order to use a pcoll as a side input it looks like you have to convert the pcoll to some kind of pvalue/view first. This one looks interesting: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.5.0/apache_beam.pvalue.html#apache_beam.pvalue.AsDict but I don't know how big of a dict it can support. Also the docs for the java version are a bit lacking https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/View.AsMap.html